# Identify the relationship between two columns and its respective value count in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a Data frame as below :

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
1       111     a       Test
2       111     b       Test
3       111     c       Test
4       222     d       Prod
5       333     e       Prod
6       333     f       Prod
7       444     g       Test
8       555     h       Prod
9       555     i       Prod
```

Expected output :

```
Column 1    Column 2    Relationship    Count
Col2        Col3        One-to-One       2
Col2        Col3        One-to-Many      3
```

Explanation :
I need to identify the relationship between Col2 & Col3 and also the value counts.

For Eg. 111(col2) is repeated 3 times and has 3 different respective values a,b,c in Col3.
This means col2 and col3 has one-to-Many relationship - count_1 : 1

222(col2) is not repeated and has only one respective value d in col3.
This means col2 and col3 has one-to-one relationshipt - count_2 : 1

333(col2) is repeated twice and has 2 different respective values e,f in col3.
This means col2 and col3 has one-to-Many relationship - count_1 : 1+1 ( increment this count for every one-to-many relationship)

Similarly for other column values increment the respective counter and display the final results as the expected dataframe.

Comment: Do you only need to check the relationship between Col2 and Col3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to check the relationship between col2 and col3, you can do:

```
(
    df.groupby(by='Col2').Col3
    .apply(lambda x: 'One-to-One' if len(x)==1 else 'One-to-Many')
    .to_frame('Relationship')
    .groupby('Relationship').Relationship
    .count().to_frame('Count').reset_index()
    .assign(**{'Column 1':'Col2', 'Column 2':'Col3'})
    .reindex(columns=['Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Relationship', 'Count'])
)
```

Output:

```
    Column 1    Column 2    Relationship    Count
0   Col2        Col3        One-to-Many     3
1   Col2        Col3        One-to-One      2
```